# /home on NFS stalls randomly

Tags: linux, nfs

I am using /home on NFS mounted via autofs for years. My workstation is Linux and server is NetBSD (for historical reasons). It was always working on NFS v3 and I had no problems with it, but recently my Fedora 34 had kernel update from 5.12 to 5.17 and NFS began to stall at certain points of usage. Full upgrade to fresh Fedora 36 have same behavior. All the options are set by default, only auto.master have "/net    -hosts" string added.

Stalling have very strange behavior. I load my desktop and it works properly to the random point when it seems that any GUI application can't create any new network connection and dmesg get kernel messages like "server xxx unavailable, still trying", but old connections continue working and any terminal can do `ls` or read files in `/home` with no limits. I suppose it is some freedesktop library stuck in some file call. Chrome or Telegram apps just can't connect to anything and Libreoffice just freeze.

Stracing stuck process show stuck read call but I could not identify the file called. Mounting /home with soft option does not help.

I had same problems before, both for NFSv3 or NFSv4, happening between different Linux distros and autofs mounts so I guess its a common problem.

I know that this description is not sufficient for getting help, but maybe someone had same problems and know how to examine the issue in detail?

Comment: Have you considered checking for bug reports and/or filing a bug? Have you already checked the logs?

Comment: This sounds similar to other situations where new connections can't be made to TCP daemons but existing connections continue to work.  Could your NFS server's rpc/nfs daemons be reaching a limit on the number of open file descriptors?

Comment: Another approach to troubleshooting would be to examine the packet statistics on the network interfaces in the NFS server and client machine.  Are the counts of dropped packets growing over time?  (they typically see a burst of dropped packets when the OS boots, so don't pay attention to the raw counts, rather check to see if the counts are growing over time)

Comment: Thanks for hints. I will create VM with that setup and try to check those advice.

Comment: Logs show nothing except what mentioned. Was searching bugs but found nothing recent.

Comment: I believe in recent 5.x versions, the in-kernel NFS client has had its caching subsystem rewritten. I wonder if you are seeing some of those changes?

Comment: Quite possible. Over the years I met NFS stability issues lot of times and most of them were caused by this cause.

Comment: Could be from network connections breaking: https://askubuntu.com/a/504278